# How can I create pivot tables in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

Are there any libraries that support creating a [pivot table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table) in JavaFX? The functionality should be similar to what Excel offers.

Comment: [TiwulFX](http://tiwulfx.panemu.com) also might work for you, or GoogleDocs/Office365 in a WebView.  Library recommendations are off topic for StackOverflow though.

Comment: Thanks, i've searched google a lot, but not find the tiwulFX.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing is [SpreadsheetView](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html) from [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/).